# JavaScript - How to update Source Code via JS

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I have a html-form with hidden input elements.

Within JS I use

> document.getElementId("xxx").value = "test";

to update hidden form elements.

After updating, I can see the updated content.

> alert(document.getElementId("xxx").value);

All good so far.

But when I look in the source code, the element value is NOT changed.

Is this possible at all?
If so, how can I change the input-value so it is also reflected
in the source code, but without reloading the website.

Thanks,
BM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code in HTML does not change
Only DOM elements is changed
You can inspect elements to see the changes of DOM in console